# Salvar o resultado de um cálculo para utilizar depois - JS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa noite pessoal, estou com um problema e não faço ideia de como resolver, recentemente iniciei um curso de Web e o assunto inicial foi JS. 
Para que eu pudesse testar meus conhecimentos, graças a dica de um amigo, decidi criar um "jogo" e consegui desenvolver boa parte do que eu tinha em mente, porém 
após efetuar o cálculo de dano após o ataque efetivo de um dos personagens e compilar o código novamente o HP de ambos retorna para o valor padrão. Minha dúvida é como salvar o novo HP dos personagens para utilizar novamente até que o mesmo atinja o zero?

Obs.: Aceito outras dicas também para que eu possa melhorar meu código/lógica

```
class StatusJob {
constructor(Job, AP, MagicResist, PhisicalResist, Strengh, HP = 1000) {
    this.Job = Job; this.AP = AP; this.MagicResist = MagicResist; this.PhisicalResist = PhisicalResist; this.Strengh = Strengh, this.HP = HP
}
}
Status_Mage = new StatusJob()
Status_Mage.Job = 'Mage'
Status_Mage.AP = 58
Status_Mage.MagicResist = 42
Status_Mage.PhisicalResist = 20
Status_Mage.Strengh = 24
Status_Mage.HP
console.log(`Your job is: ${Status_Mage.Job}`)
console.log(`Your hability power is: ${Status_Mage.AP}`)
console.log(`Your magic resist is: ${Status_Mage.MagicResist}`)
console.log(`Your phisical resist is: ${Status_Mage.PhisicalResist}`)
console.log(`Your strengh is: ${Status_Mage.Strengh}`)
console.log(`Your hit point is: ${Status_Mage.HP}`)
console.log(`
`)

Status_Warrior = new StatusJob()
Status_Warrior.Job = 'Warrior'
Status_Warrior.AP = 10
Status_Warrior.MagicResist = 25
Status_Warrior.PhisicalResist = 45
Status_Warrior.Strengh = 65
Status_Warrior.HP
console.log(`Your job is: ${Status_Warrior.Job}`)
console.log(`Your hability power is: ${Status_Warrior.AP}`)
console.log(`Your magic resist is: ${Status_Warrior.MagicResist}`)
console.log(`Your phisical resist is: ${Status_Warrior.PhisicalResist}`)
console.log(`Your strengh is: ${Status_Warrior.Strengh}`)
console.log(`Your hit point is: ${Status_Warrior.HP}`)
console.log(`
`)

function rateCritM(min = 0, max = 100) {
let percentage = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
return this.Math.floor(percentage)
}

function rateCritG(min = 0, max = 100) {
let percentage = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
return this.Math.floor(percentage)
}
function rateAccM(min = 0, max = 100) {
let percentage = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
return this.Math.floor(percentage)
}
function rateAccG(min = 0, max = 100) {
let percentage = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
return this.Math.floor(percentage)
}
function rateEvaM(min = 0, max = 100) {
let percentage = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
return this.Math.floor(percentage)
}
function rateEvaG(min = 0, max = 100) {
let percentage = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
return this.Math.floor(percentage)
}

const percentageCritM = rateCritM()
const percentageCritG = rateCritG()
const rateAccuracyG = rateAccG()
const rateAccuracyM = rateAccM()
const rateEvasionG = rateEvaG()
const rateEvasionM = rateEvaM()

const MageAttack = function () {
if (rateAccuracyM < rateEvasionG) {
    console.log(`The Warrior managed to evade his attack! The avoidance rate was: ${rateEvasionG}`)
    console.log(`Mage's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyM} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritM <= 20 && percentageCritM >= 10) {
    Status_Mage.AP = Status_Mage.AP + (Status_Mage.AP * 1 / 4)
    console.log(`Mage's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritM} and was 1/4 more powerful for this hit!`)
    Status_Warrior.HP = Status_Warrior.HP - (Status_Mage.AP - Status_Warrior.MagicResist)
    console.log(`The Warrior got ${Status_Warrior.HP} of hit point, after the mage's assault`)
    console.log(`Mage's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyM} %`)
    console.log(`The Warrior's evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionG} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritM <= 40 && percentageCritM >= 21) {
    Status_Mage.AP = Status_Mage.AP + (Status_Mage.AP * 2 / 4)
    console.log(`Mage's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritM} and was 2/4 more powerful for this hit!`)
    Status_Warrior.HP = Status_Warrior.HP - (Status_Mage.AP - Status_Warrior.MagicResist)
    console.log(`The Warrior got ${Status_Warrior.HP} of hit point, after the mage's assault`)
    console.log(`Mage's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyM} %`)
    console.log(`The Warrior's evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionG} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritM <= 60 && percentageCritM >= 41) {
    Status_Mage.AP = Status_Mage.AP + (Status_Mage.AP * 3 / 4)
    console.log(`Mage's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritM} and was 3/4 more powerful for this hit!`)
    Status_Warrior.HP = Status_Warrior.HP - (Status_Mage.AP - Status_Warrior.MagicResist)
    console.log(`The Warrior got ${Status_Warrior.HP} of hit point, after the mage's assault`)
    console.log(`Mage's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyM} %`)
    console.log(`The Warrior's evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionG} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritM >= 61) {
    Status_Mage.AP = Status_Mage.AP * 2
    console.log(`Mage's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritM} and was TWICE more powerful for this hit!!`)
    Status_Warrior.HP = Status_Warrior.HP - (Status_Mage.AP - Status_Warrior.MagicResist)
    console.log(`The Warrior got ${Status_Warrior.HP} of hit point, after the mage's assault`)
    console.log(`Mage's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyM} %`)
    console.log(`The Warrior's evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionG} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritM <= 10) {
    Status_Warrior.HP = Status_Warrior.HP - (Status_Mage.AP - Status_Warrior.MagicResist)
    console.log(`Mage's attack had no critical hit and gave his base damage`)
    console.log(`The Warrior got ${Status_Warrior.HP} of hit point, after the mage's assault`)
    console.log(`Mage's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyM} %`)
    console.log(`The Warrior's evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionG} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} 

}

const WarriorAttack = function () {
if (rateAccuracyG < rateEvasionM) {
    console.log(`Mage managed to evade his attack! The avoidance rate was: ${rateEvasionM}`)
    console.log(`Warrior's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyG} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritG <= 20 && percentageCritG >= 10) {
    Status_Warrior.Strengh = Status_Warrior.Strengh + (Status_Warrior.Strengh * 1 / 4)
    console.log(`Warrior's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritG} and was 1/4 more powerful for this hit!`)
    Status_Mage.HP = Status_Mage.HP - (Status_Warrior.Strengh - Status_Mage.PhisicalResist)
    console.log(`Mage got ${Status_Mage.HP}, after the warrior's assault`)
    console.log(`Warrior's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyG} %`)
    console.log(`The Mage evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionM} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritG <= 40 && percentageCritG >= 21) {
    Status_Warrior.Strengh = Status_Warrior.Strengh + (Status_Warrior.Strengh * 2 / 4)
    console.log(`Warrior's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritG} and was 2/4 more powerful for this hit!`)
    Status_Mage.HP = Status_Mage.HP - (Status_Warrior.Strengh - Status_Mage.PhisicalResist)
    console.log(`Mage got ${Status_Mage.HP} of hit point, after the warrior's assault`)
    console.log(`Warrior's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyG} %`)
    console.log(`The Mage evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionM} %`)
    console.log(`
    `)
} else if (percentageCritG <= 60 && percentageCritG >= 41) {
    Status_Warrior.Strengh = Status_Warrior.Strengh + (Status_Warrior.Strengh * 3 / 4)
    console.log(`Warrior's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritG} e ficou 3/4 mais poderoso para este acerto!`)
    Status_Mage.HP = Status_Mage.HP - (Status_Warrior.Strengh - Status_Mage.PhisicalResist)
    console.log(`Mage got ${Status_Mage.HP} of hit point, after the warrior's assault`)
    console.log(`Warrior's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyG} %`)
    console.log(`The Mage evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionM} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritG >= 61) {
    Status_Warrior.Strengh = Status_Warrior.Strengh * 2
    console.log(`Warrior's attack had a critical hit on ${percentageCritG} and was TWICE more powerful for this hit!!`)
    Status_Mage.HP = Status_Mage.HP - (Status_Warrior.Strengh - Status_Mage.PhisicalResist)
    console.log(`Mage got ${Status_Mage.HP} of hit point, after the warrior's assault`)
    console.log(`Warrior's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyG} %`)
    console.log(`The Mage evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionM} %`)
    console.log(`
     `)
} else if (percentageCritG <= 10) {
    Status_Mage.HP = Status_Mage.HP - (Status_Warrior.Strengh - Status_Mage.PhisicalResist)
    console.log(`Warrior's attack had no critical hit and gave his base damage`)
    console.log(`Mage got ${Status_Mage.HP} of hit point, after the warrior's assault`)
    console.log(`Warrior's accuracy rate in this attack was: ${rateAccuracyG} %`)
    console.log(`The Mage evasion rate in this attack was: ${rateEvasionM} %`)
} 

}

MageAttack()
WarriorAttack()

console.log(`The Warrior got ${Status_Warrior.HP} of current hit point, after the Mage's assault`)
console.log(`The Mage got ${Status_Mage.HP} of current hit point, after the Warrior's assault`)
```

Comment: Se não for utilizar bancos de dados, pesquise por cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage ou outra forma de armazenamento do lado cliente.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, consegui resolver o problema com o localStorage!

Comment: seria ideal voce postar sua solução e marca-la como resolvido. assim mais pessoas no futuro podem ser ajudadas ;)